# Work with files exception

Tags: .net, visual-c++, file

I want to create program which will tell me if a file is used or not by another processes (for example i open music or video file in multimedia player, and then i launch my program with this file name programm return "this file is being used", and when no processes uses this file program would say "this file not being used").

What classes have the .NET for solve this problem?

Comment: You might wish to look at sources of "handle" utility from sysinternals. They do it, although not in .NET, but it should be easy to transcode.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [ETW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx) tracing for [File I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363884(VS.85).aspx) which should help you figure out File I/O events. And here is how you can use ETW within [managed code](http://naveensrinivasan.com/etw/)